# Good tutorial on how install Hadoop 2.2.0 (Yarn) as single node cluster on MacOS

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to install Apache Hadoop 2.2.0 on my MacOS as single-node cluster and unable to find any documentation which helps to complete setup without errors. All guidelines I found so far on Hadoop, Cloudera and other web sites are either lack details or contain outdated information. Can anyone refer to consistent and clean step-by-step instruction which really works for single-node Apache Hadoop 2.2.0 setup on MacOS ?

Comment: Just [install steps](http://www.diaryfolio.com/hadoop-install-steps/) for Hadoop 2.3.0 with Yarn

Comment: I would suggest to install VirtualBox on your MacOS with CentOS 6.6 and install Hadoop there.  Here is my tutorial - http://ihorbobak.com/index.php/2015/05/06/installing-hadoop-using-ambari-server/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hi I am faced with the same problem as you and I stumbled upon this recent tutorial for hadoop 2.2.0 on [this](http://codesfusion.blogspot.com/2013/10/setup-hadoop-2x-220-on-ubuntu.html?m=1) blog.

Also [this guide](http://dasunhegoda.com/hadoop-2-deployment-installation-ubuntu/1085/) explains Hadoop 2 Deployment on Ubuntu step by step. Very useful.

Comment: Yeah, this one looks accurate. Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://nextgenhadoop.blogspot.in/2013/10/steps-to-install-hadoop-220-stable.html

Comment: I struggled installing hadoop from source, not the compile of maven install part, but rather the final installation steps of putting exes in the right directories (/libexec etc.). There appears to be nothing out there to describe how this is done and the documentation is a complete blank. I got hadoop going by downloading the 'installed' version (that comes with its /bin, /sbin, /libexec, /conf) etc directories (but no source) and using Naveen's tutorial. I was surprised there wasn't more out there, and the Apache site was useless for this version (yarn). Hopefully that will change soon.

Comment: Very bad tutorial. Not advisable!

Comment: @toom why is this a bad tutorial?

Answer (score 25):

I recently wrote a [guide of my own](http://www.alexjf.net/blog/distributed-systems/hadoop-yarn-installation-definitive-guide) as I also found the official documentation lacking and because all other guides seem to be stuck on the pre-YARN hadoop mentality and are full of no longer necessary steps/environment values. I also included a Fabric script for easy cluster deployment. I would love your feedback!

Comment: this answer is better than the accepted one. Thanks

Comment: Agree. This is better than the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2012/01/getting-started-with-nextgen-mapreduce_11.html) are the instructions for installing YARN on Ubuntu 12.04. But, with little modification the same should apply for a Mac also.

Comment: Praveen, thanks for referring. I saw this tutorial before and it actually the good one... Much better then official Apache "getting started". 
However it has the same problem - a number of discrepancies preventing from successful setup of latest stable Hadoop version. 
For example - Hadoop 2.2.0 aux-services name was changed from "mapreduce.shuffle" to "mapreduce_shuffle", replication factor for single node install would be 1, not 2 and so on and on.

Comment: Have updated the blog accordingly - thnx.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it is good tutorial but after abiding to it what i got on 'jps' was that there were no Namenode and Datanode entry.

http://codesfusion.blogspot.com/2013/10/setup-hadoop-2x-220-on-ubuntu.html?m=1

Here, is the updated version of that post which worked for me.

http://javatute.com/javatute/faces/post/hadoop/2014/setting-hadoop-2.2.0-on-ubuntu-12-lts.xhtml

Comment: That could be caused because you didn't configure fs.default.name. Also ensure to open and close all xml file properties ex: <property><name>fs.default.name</name><value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value></property>

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this great and simple tuto http://raseshmori.wordpress.com/2012/09/23/install-hadoop-2-0-1-yarn-nextgen/

Comment: Is installation of Hadoop 2.x also needs configuration of SSH as prerequisite?